# using waf in my CMake for C++ project

Tags: cmake, build-process, waf

I am working on a project written in c++ and using CMake to compile and make to build source files. I also have an external library which use "waf" for compiling and building. 
I am wondering How I can include this external library in my CMakeList file and use it withing the main project.

Thanks for you r help in advance.

Comment: ??? no answer just marking????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at CMake's [`ExternalProject`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#module%3aExternalProject) module.

This can be used to build arbitrary third-party dependencies from within CMake, even if they use a build system different from CMake themselves.